# Extract Website Images From HTML Alt Element VBA

Tags: html, css, excel, vba

I'm looking to extract images from a subscription website. The image's html code looks like this:

```
<img chart-id="2669" alt="Chart ID 2669" class="chart-img" 
  src="https://website.com/img_2054_569134694870.jpg"
  diagnostic-id="chart-img-1" style="max-height: 150px;">
```

Looking at the code I figure referencing the alt id is my best bet. So my code looks like this.

```
Sub ImportImage()

    Dim Cell As Integer
    Dim ItemNbr As String

    Dim AElement As Object
    Dim AElements As IHTMLElementCollection

    Dim IE As MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
    Set IE = New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60

    Dim HTMLDoc As MSHTML.HTMLDocument
    Dim HTMLBody As MSHTML.HTMLBody

    Set HTMLDoc = New MSHTML.HTMLDocument
    Set HTMLBody = HTMLDoc.body

       
        IE.Open "GET", "https://app.website.com/22920", False
        IE.send

        While IE.readyState <> 4
            DoEvents
        Wend

        HTMLBody.innerHTML = IE.responseText

        Set pImg = HTMLDoc.getElementById("Chart ID 2669")
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B7") = pImg.getAttribute("alt")

        Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:2"))


End Sub
```

This code is pretty weak, but I'm trying to build it out so I can import the website image into my workbook. Any advice? Thanks!

```
  Sub NEWUPDATEDImportImage()

   Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
  strURL = "https://website.com/chartbooks/22920"
  IE.navigate strURL
  IE.Visible = True
  
Dim HTMLDoc As MSHTML.HTMLDocument
Dim HTMLBody As MSHTML.HTMLBody

Set HTMLDoc = New MSHTML.HTMLDocument
Set HTMLBody = HTMLDoc.body
HTMLBody.innerHTML = IE.responseText
    

        Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1") = HTMLDoc.querySelector("img[alt='Chart ID 2669']").getAttribute("src")


End Sub
```

Comment: I removed the PHP tag, it's all vba code

Comment: alt property is Not `alt ID`. so you can't use `getElementById` by property 'alt id'

Comment: loop all element in doc And check `if tempElement.getAttribute("alt") = "Chart ID 2669"`

Comment: Thanks @Sacru2red, could you explain a little more about your last comment? If I include this line instead of  `Set pImg = HTMLDoc.getElementById("Chart ID 2669")` how should I put that image into a cell?

Comment: @Sacru2red I have something like this, which doesn't work. `For Each Elem In IE.document.getElementsByTagName("img")
If IE.tempElement.getAttribute("alt") = "Chart ID 2669" Then
Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1") = IE.document.getElementsByTagName("img").getAttribute("src")`

Comment: 'loop all element' don't mean that loop why your code is lopping one depth element only /

Comment: Ah, I see, its because I tried "looping" in my first attempt at building the code.

Comment: Also, you can avoid looping by using the querySelector method with either `HTMLDoc.querySelector("img[alt='Chart ID 2669']").getAttribute("src")` or `HTMLDoc.querySelector("img[chart-id='2669']").getAttribute("src")`.

Comment: @Domenic Thanks for the input. I tried altering my code. See my OP's new code at the end. I tried your method, but I'm still receiving an error that the object doesn't support this property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're mixing the code for both XML and IE approaches.  Also, you should check to make sure that the page is finished loading before proceeding.  Try the following instead...

```
Option Explicit

Sub ImportImage()

    Dim IE As Object
    Dim HTMLDoc As Object
    Dim HTMLImg As Object
    Dim strURL As String
    
    strURL = "https://website.com/chartbooks/22920"
    
    Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    
    With IE
        .Visible = True
        .navigate strURL
        Do While .Busy Or .readyState <> 4 '4 = READYSTATE_COMPLETE
            DoEvents
        Loop
        Set HTMLDoc = .document
    End With
    
    On Error Resume Next
    Set HTMLImg = HTMLDoc.querySelector("img[alt='Chart ID 2669']")
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    With Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1")
        If Not HTMLImg Is Nothing Then
            .Value = HTMLImg.getattribute("src")
        Else
            .Value = "Image not found"
        End If
    End With
    
    Set IE = Nothing
    Set HTMLDoc = Nothing
    Set HTMLImg = Nothing
    
End Sub
```